# What do we call the $\alpha$ in Riemann Integral?

Tags: riemann-integration

I am learning the concept of Riemann Integral.

$F(x) \text{ sometimes denoted as} \int_a^xfd\alpha$.

What I know is $\alpha$ is a function which maps $x\mapsto\Bbb R$(Is this domain and codomain correct?)

But I want to know with which term we call this $\alpha$

Comment: A dummy variable?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html

Comment: But isn't it a function? So it might be.. dummy function? This sounds little bit weired to me

Comment: See my answer. ${}$

Comment: With the standard Riemann integral, you can think of it as the identity function, but can be something other than the identity function with a generalization of Riemann integral called the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, then $\alpha$ is called the *integrator*.